# Finding a subkey with a view in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

How do I go about creating a view that would allow me to search for a particular value based on a JSON object with the main document?

For example, below is a document from my database.
Phone number is kept in "phone" which is within the "patientinfo" key.

How would I search for a phone number with this layout?

```
  {
   "_id": "x2484",
   "_rev": "2-44ac5e42ce95fcbcc8a743a256a3f6ce",
   "patientinfo": {
       "name": "Douglas",
       "laststat": "Complete",
       "timetocall": 1438034383,
       "queue": 7,
       "notes": "Spouse placed call",
       "laststatcode": 501,
       "timestamp": 1438023283,
       "phone": 3141592653,
       "attempts": 1
   },
   "call": {
       "1": {
           "timetocall": 1438034383,
           "status": "Complete",
           "laststat": "Complete",
           "timestamp": 1438023283,
           "lastintv": "moor",
           "laststatcode": 501
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer turned out to be much simpler than I thought. All I needed to do was add the next level of the json object as part of my if and emit statements.

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.patientinfo.phone)
  {
  emit(doc.patientinfo.phone, doc);
  }
}
```